# How do I set the ZipArchive compression level using addGlob()?

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

Would like to create a smaller file using ZipArchive but using the addGlob option... so I don't know what to use.
**using php 5.6**

Without the setCompressionIndex line of code, the entire thing works fine.

TRIED

```
$zip->setCompressionName( '*', ZipArchive::CM_DEFLATE );
```

AND TRIED

```
$zip->setCompressionIndex( '*', ZipArchive::CM_DEFLATE );
```

MY CODE

```
<?php
    // SOME OTHER STUFF BEFORE
    $options = array( 'add_path' => 'PRJ/', 'remove_all_path' => TRUE );
    $zip->addGlob( '../matter/prj/' . $prj_group . '/' . $prj_id . '/img/prj/*.*', GLOB_BRACE, $options );

    $zip->setCompressionIndex( 1, ZipArchive::CM_DEFLATE );
    $zip->close();
?>
```

ACTUAL RESULTS

```
Call to undefined method ZipArchive::setCompressionName()
Call to undefined method ZipArchive::setCompressionIndex()
```

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that I need (PHP 7, PECL zip >= 1.13.0).